# Unable to connect to the Administration Server weblogic 12.2.1

Tags: ssl, weblogic, ssl-certificate, weblogic12c

I have a WebLogic domain whit an Admin server and one Managed Server. I installed the certificate for ssl connection beetwen Admin and Managed, but when I restart the Managed I have this error:

```
<May 2, 2016 6:39:24 PM CEST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141307> <Unable to connect to the Administration Server. Waiting 5 second(s) to retry (attempt number 3 of 3).>
<May 2, 2016 6:39:29 PM CEST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141298> <Could not register with the Administration Server: java.rmi.RemoteException: [Deployer:149150]An IOException occurred while reading the input.; nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem>
```

I changed this option:
admin console Servers -> server name -> Configuration SSL tab -> Advanced -> Change Hostname Verification dropdown to None

Version 12.2.1

Do you have any solutions?

Thanks
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

There's probably some problem with the SSL certificate.  I would recommend to double check that and also rerun with  -Dssl.debug added to the Weblogic command line to get more information.  Then check both the admin and managed server log files, as it might have enough information to answer.  If not, please and add more information here.